# Python Multipleclient Server with Queues

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, queue

I have a server, that should accept multiple connections from clients, execute orders which can take some times, in a specific priority, and respond back to each client when it's task is done.
I've tried to write a basic implementation of this, to make it work before it actually does something.

I want to respond back to the client only when it's task is done, which i've tried to achieve by passing the `conn` object to the queue item and sending via it, the problem is that when executing task from the first connected client (assuming I have 2 or more clients that are connected, pending for answer), the server responded to all clients.

The code:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import Queue
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)

BUFFER_SIZE = 20
commands_queue = Queue.PriorityQueue(BUFFER_SIZE)

class Command(object):
    def __init__(self, priority, data, conn):
        self.priority = priority
        self.data = data
        self.conn = conn

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.priority, other.priority)


class CommandsThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.target = target
        self.name = name


    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not commands_queue.empty():
                command = commands_queue.get()
                logging.debug("Queueing data: " + command.data)
                time.sleep(3)
                logging.debug("Finshed queue: " + command.data)
                command.conn.send("Done: " + command.data)  # echo

# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Thread Pool
class ClientThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        print "[+] New server socket thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            print "Server received data:", data
            if not commands_queue.full():
                if data.startswith("a"):
                    commands_queue.put(Command(1, data, conn))
                else:
                    commands_queue.put(Command(2, data, conn))
                # conn.send("Done: " + data)  # echo


# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Program Stub
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'
TCP_PORT = 2004


tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

c = CommandsThread(name='commands')
c.start()
threads.append(c)

while True:
    tcpServer.listen(4)
    print "Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients..."
    (conn, (ip, port)) = tcpServer.accept()
    newthread = ClientThread(ip, port)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

I thought that inside `ClientThread.run`, waiting for the command that has been put to finish and then send the answer inside that function without doing it inside the `CommandsThread` will be a good solution, but I can't find on the web on how to wait for this specific command to finish.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try create conn param at ClientThread and passing new connection to it. And when you put new command to queue - pass self.conn instead of conn.

I've tryed your code on python3 with my suggestion improvements and it worked fine.

Server ( python2 ):

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import Queue
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)

BUFFER_SIZE = 20
commands_queue = Queue.PriorityQueue(BUFFER_SIZE)

class Command(object):
    def __init__(self, priority, data, conn):
        self.priority = priority
        self.data = data
        self.conn = conn

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.priority, other.priority)


class CommandsThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.target = target
        self.name = name


    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not commands_queue.empty():
                command = commands_queue.get()
                logging.debug("Queueing data: " + command.data)
                time.sleep(3)
                logging.debug("Finshed queue: " + command.data)
                command.conn.send("Done: " + command.data)  # echo

# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Thread Pool
class ClientThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn, ip, port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = conn
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        print "[+] New server socket thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            print "Server received data:", data
            if not commands_queue.full():
                if data.startswith("a"):
                    commands_queue.put(Command(1, data, self.conn))
                else:
                    commands_queue.put(Command(2, data, self.conn))
                # conn.send("Done: " + data)  # echo


# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Program Stub
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'
TCP_PORT = 2004


tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

c = CommandsThread(name='commands')
c.start()
threads.append(c)

while True:
    tcpServer.listen(4)
    print "Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients..."
    (conn, (ip, port)) = tcpServer.accept()
    newthread = ClientThread(ip, port)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Client ( python2 ):

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 2004
sock.connect((host,port))
while True:
    data = raw_input("message: ")
    sock.send(data)
    while True:
        print("response: ", sock.recv(1024))
```

Comment: Putting conn as a param like you've suggested does solve it :) many thanks